# How to fix "no installation candidate" error installing pessulus on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation

How can I install pessulus on Ubuntu 12.10? We are currently upgrading hardware and Ubuntu 12.10 supports the multi-touch screen that we're about to use.

When I enter the command `apt-get install pessulus` in the command line, I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package pessulus is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pessulus' has no installation candidate
```

What do I need to do to install pessulus? I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though `pessulus` was dropped from Ubuntu [due to compatibility issues with Gnome 3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes):

> Nanny, Pessulus and Sabayon haven't been ported to Gnome 3.0/dconf yet and were consequently dropped from the default installation.

This happened as early as Ubuntu 11.10. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pessulus/+bug/549854) for a related bug report